# Do there exist ways to consume Android memory such that the VM will offload other apps?

Tags: android, memory

We want to test, in our android app, the behaviour when the VM closes the app due to other applications consuming too much memory.

Is there an app to simulate this sort of memory-hog behaviour that correctly induces the right actions in the android VM?

Alternatively: is there a way to cause the equivalent signal while using Eclipse to force the system to pretend like there's a huge memory hog of an app out there?

Answer (score 0):

No, every application has its own heap size limit and will all be killed if OOM thinks that it is malfunctioning. If you want to seize the memory, try to do it in the native code, it is out side the DVM management.

Comment: No Java APP does this. You can simply write your own C program